# Displaying an icon on the AIR Application Installation Screen

Tags: installation, air, windows-installer

Is it possible to display an icon on the AIR Application Installation Screen?

I downloaded an AIR application, and I was surprised to see an icon on the second installation screen.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is it possible because of the purchasing Digitally signed certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you purchase SSL certificate and make air application build with that certificate, then this icon is showed during installation.

Comment: And where do you set this icon source?

Comment: I am using Code Signing Certificate and the icon is not showing. Can you specify what is this SSL certificate?

Answer (score 0):

In your main-app.xml config file look for the `<icon>` tag and set an image file for the `<image128x128>` tag relative to your src folder eg.

```
<icon>
    <image16x16>/assets/icons/16x16.png</image16x16>
    <image32x32>/assets/icons/32x32.png</image32x32>
    <image48x48>/assets/icons/48x48.png</image48x48>        
    <image128x128>/assets/icons/128x128.png</image128x128>
</icon>
```

These different sizes cover you for different eventualities such as OSX dock, XP quick launch and also for the installer.