# Can a custom image be added to Adobe AIR desktop application installer

Tags: image, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I am developing desktop application with Flex and AIR and exporting it for both OS X and Windows. I am wondering how can I add a custom image (logo of the application) to he installer. So when the user starts the installer he will se the logo on the top right section.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying an icon on the AIR Application Installation Screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574321/displaying-an-icon-on-the-air-application-installation-screen)

Comment: For Windows... This **[method](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/customize-setup-for-AIR-app-with-captive-runtime.html)** could be an option.

Answer (score 0):

We used custom installers platform specific installers (and application update dialogs) for Win and OS-X that wrapped the Air silent installation process. Depending upon your desired end-user experience this is one way to go. It is a lot more initial work that may or may not be worth the time.

> Silent installation
>
> Generally, the AIR Installer presents its own user interface while
>   installing the runtime and the AIR application. The silent
>   installation feature lets you install an application without
>   presenting or interacting with the AIR Installer interface.
>
> You can use silent mode to install Adobe AIR using an enterprise
>   deployment tool (such as Microsoft SMS, IBM Tivoli, or any deployment
>   tool that allows silent installations that use a bootstrapper).
>
> To run the Adobe AIR installer silently, start the Adobe AIR installer
>   with the following command-line options:
>
> -silent {-eulaAccepted -pingbackAllowed ( -location <loc> ) -desktopShortcut -programMenu} path

Ref: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/redist/WS485a42d56cd19641-70d979a8124ef20a34b-8000.html

Also you would need to bundle the Air runtime:

> Obtaining permission to redistribute the runtime
>
> To obtain permission to redistribute Adobe AIR, read the Adobe AIR
>   Runtime Distribution Agreement and apply for a license: Adobe® AIR™
>   Runtime Distribution.
>
> Also, be sure to read the Adobe AIR FAQ page, which contains important
>   information on the runtime distribution and license terms: Adobe® AIR™
>   Runtime Distribution FAQ.
>
> Important: You may distribute Adobe AIR with your product only if you
>   follow the Adobe AIR Runtime Distribution License Agreement
>   application process and are then approved by Adobe. Otherwise, users
>   can download and install Adobe AIR from the adobe.com site.

Ref: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/redist/WS485a42d56cd19641-70d979a8124ef20a34b-8000.html

We also provided our own custom application update user interface so the end-user saw our update dialog vs. the built-in Air dialog:

> customUpdateUI
>
> Indicates whether an application will provide its own update dialogs.
>   If false, AIR presents standard update dialogs to the user. Only
>   applications distributed as AIR files can use the built-in AIR update
>   system.
>
> When the installed version of your application has the customUpdateUI
>   element set to true and the user then double-clicks the AIR file for a
>   new version or installs an update of the application using the
>   seamless install feature, the runtime opens the installed version of
>   the application. The runtime does not open the default AIR application
>   installer. Your application logic can then determine how to proceed
>   with the update operation. (The application ID and publisher ID in the
>   AIR file must match the values in the installed application for an
>   upgrade to proceed.)
>
> Note: The customUpdateUI mechanism only comes into play when the
>   application is already installed and the user double-clicks the AIR
>   installation file containing an update or installs an update of the
>   application using the seamless install feature. You can download and
>   start an update through your own application logic, displaying your
>   custom UI as necessary, whether or not customUpdateUI is true.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ccd.html